# WCF binding configuration apply only as default but as named it fails

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcf-binding

We have an interesting problem with WCF binding and streaming transfer mode that we cannot solve:

We have an WCF endpoint configured to the streaming transfer mode. The endpoint receives message much larger then the default size (~65 KB). Therefore we have specified larger message size in the maxReceivedMessageSize attribute on the binding tag.

The problem is when we pair up the endpoint and the binding by the *bindingConfiguration* attribute on the *endpoint* tag and the *name* attribute on the *binding* tag, we receive the following error: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".

As soon as we remove both attributes *bindingConfiguration* and *name* it works without an error.

Here is the definition of the service **endpoint**:

```
    <service name="Services.DocumentService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint contract="ServiceContracts.IDocumentService" address="DocumentService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration"     <---- when this goes away
              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceEndpointBehavior"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Documents/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    </service>
```

Here is the **binding configuration**:

```
    <binding  
      name="BindingConfiguration" <---- and when this goes away
     transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
```

So it only works as default binding (without explicitly named key). The strange thing is that we were able to verify by reflection on the Service host that the binding configuration is actually applied (the maxReceivedMessageSize was set correctly) in both scenarios. Could it be a bug in WCF?

The service is self-hosted.

Any ideas are very appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried it with a different name other than BindingConfiguration say "test" or something

Comment: We have tried alternative names, even such as 'xx', 'xxx', 'z' :-)

Comment: @Honzajscz Have you found a solution to the issue? I have exactly the same problem and I can't figure out why it doesn't work with a named binding configuration... I can't just use an empty string because if I have another service to host with a different configuration, it wouldn't work anymore. EDIT: btw, I'm not using streamed transferMode.

Comment: @ken2k We have done unfortunately no progress in the issue. We just use the default binding.

Comment: @Honzajscz Hi, I just read your answer. Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you. In the meantime, I've created [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041931/error-400-bad-request-maxreceivedmessagesize-not-taken-into-account-for-my-wc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have recently found out that the initialization code used explicitly the default settings and thus ignored those in the web.config.

We removed that part of code and the setting from the web.config got applied.

A stupid error.

Thanks everybody for thier answers

Comment: What part you removed? I Also removed "basicHttpBinding" but it still not working...

Comment: @John We used a C# code to initialize the service. The initialization C# code was ignoring the setting in the web.config and ignored our biding setting.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration", it uses default values not the values in your binding configuration.

The difference is:

```
transferMode="Streamed"
```

By default the transfer mode is buffered, so if the client expects buffered and the server uses streamed, then you get a bad request error.

Comment: When we remove 'bindingConfiguration="BindingConfiguration"' it actually starts to works and we can upload files much larger that the defualt 65k. Client is set to streaming as well.

It behaves in such a way that it actually seems to be using the binding without name, if you omit the bindingConfiguration.