# Error 400 (bad request): maxReceivedMessageSize not taken into account for my WCF service

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, web-config, wcf-binding

> There are multiple related questions on SO (almost same title), none of them helped me to
>   fix my problem. Please do not close my question as duplicate before
>   reading it. Thanks.

I'm currently using WCF to expose a webservice (SOAP, HTTP). It is deployed in IIS Express for now. My problem is, I can't manage to consume my service from my client. My client receives a `HTTP Error 400 Bad request` exception.

I've then activated tracing on server side to see what's actually happening, here's what I get:

[image]

I've translated the error message into English: `The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`.

Pretty self-explanatory, actually. As my SOAP message is quite heavy, it probably exceeds the limit of 64KB.

I decided to extends this limit in the binding configuration. So here's my web.config (server side):

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="MyBindingConfiguration"
              bindingNamespace="http://my_namespace"
              contract="XXX.IMyContract" />
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingConfiguration"
             allowCookies="true"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

As you can see, all sizes are set to `int.MaxValue`.

I've also modified my client app.config, here it is:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBindingName"
             allowCookies="false"
             bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text"
             textEncoding="utf-8"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">

      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:8083/myAddress.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="MyBindingName"
            contract="IMyContract"
            name="MyBindingName" />
</client>
```

I then redeployed my service, and the issue was still here (`HTTP 400, Bad request` on client side + `MaxReceivedMessageSize limited to 65536` on server side).

I then tested my service with a very small SOAP message: **everything is perfectly fine**. So the problem is really that my message is bigger than 64KB.

I spent 2 hours yesterday trying to figure out what's the problem with my configuration... Probably something obvious, but I can't find...

I've googled a lot about this problem, 95% of time the issue is the developer forgot to specify the `bindingConfiguration` attribute in the service endpoint. As you can see in my web.config above, it's OK for me.

Then I've found [another question on stackoverflow about the (almost) same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910566/wcf-binding-configuration-apply-only-as-default-but-as-named-it-fails#comment12845134_9910566).

As the author said in his question, setting the name of the binding configuration to `string.Empty` "fixes" the problem:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration=""
...

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name=""
...
```

When using the default binding, everything works fine. I can't just fix my problem using this workaround because I need to specify multiple different binding configurations in the same web.config.

I'm recreating a question here because it's not actually the same conditions: my service is not self-hosted but hosted in IIS Express (or IIS 7.5, tested, same problem).

I've found a [similar issue here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/356197/MaxReceivedMessageSize-does-not-work) with a self-hosted service, and the issue was related to this particularity. So I think there is something different between those 2 SO questions.

I guess there's something obviously wrong in my configuration, but I can't find what.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine at first glance - only point is: the `<service name=".....">` attribute **must** match exactly to your fully-qualified service implementation class (including all namespaces etc.) - is that the case?? I ask because you have `contract="XXX.IMyContract"` indicating a namespace, but your `serviec name="...."` attribute doesn't have any namespace hinted at ....

Comment: What you could do in your server (and client) config is to define **no name** for the binding configuration, e.g. have `<bindings> <basicHttpBinding> <binding ......>` without a `name="MyBinding"` attribute. In that case, that binding configuration will be applied to **all** endpoints using that binding (if they do not specify a specific binding configuration to use).

Comment: @marc_s You're absolutely right: I forgot to specify the namespace for the service name. I just tested my service with the full qualified name, it now works as expected! I would never have found this alone. Why the hell was my service working perfectly fine with a small SOAP message? Specifying the service name without the namespace broke the binding configuration, not the service itself (it even works fine for a small message with a random name !). This is a very strange behavior IMO. Anyway, you solved my problem, please write this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine at first glance - only point is: the `<service name=".....">` attribute must match **exactly** to your fully-qualified service implementation class (including all namespaces etc.) - is that the case??

I ask because you have `contract="XXX.IMyContract"` indicating a namespace, but your `<service name="....">` attribute doesn't have any namespace hinted at.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks. As said in the comments, "Specifying the service name without the namespace broke the binding configuration, not the service itself (it even works fine for a small message with a random name !)". May I ask you if you have any idea about why the service behaves this way?

Comment: @ken2k: I believe you've become "victim" of the new WCF 4 default behaviors. If WCF 4 cannot find a configuration for a service (because it's not there, or the service name is misspelled), it will just use some system defaults - like HTTP as the protocol and a binding for HTTP. This is most likely what happened to you - the WCF 4 runtime spun up your service - but only with default settings, e.g. the 64K default message size - even though you had a config.

Comment: marc_s, I wanted to thank you for your thorough explanation on the matter (this just resolved an identical issue that I was having). What a frustrating "feature", this default behavior nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try by the following web-config settings in service :

```
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>

            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"                                        
                                  crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" 
                                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                                  maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                                  maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" />
            </webHttpEndpoint>

    </standardEndpoints>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding>
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```